# Recursive Promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I am trying to build out relationships in a dataset I have stored in Elasticsearch.  I am currently having trouble returning all of the results of the relationship.  When I run the recursive function, it only returns the first result it finds.  I am having a hard time understanding promises and how to use them correctly for my purpose.  Any help to get this to return all of the data would be appreciated.

server.js call when a button is clicked:

```
app.get('/parent/:elemName', function (req, res) {
  var elemName = req.params.elemName;
  streams.getUpstream(elemName).then(function (resp) { console.log("***** " + resp); });
});
```

second.js where getUpstream from the previous code sample is called:

```
exports.getUpstream = function (element) {
  return getStream(element, 'parent');
};
```

getStream function that is called in getUpstream above:

```
function getStream(element, direction) {
  var stream = [];

  function climb(elementName) {
    return search.getDetails(elementName).then(function (searchResult) {
      var element = searchResult.hits.hits[0]._source.versions[0];
      var parents = element[direction];
      console.log("stream " + stream);
      // Base case
      if (!parents) return [];

      // Recursive case
      var promises = parents.map(function (parent) {
        if (!_.includes(stream, parent)) {
          console.log("inside " + parent);
          stream.push(parent);
          climb(parent);
        }
      });
      return stream;
    });
  }

  return climb(element);
}
```

The first code snippet calls the getUpstream method and prints out the result.  The console.log will eventually do a res.send of the data instead.  The log is for debugging purposes.

The second code snippet calls getStream and merely acts as a bridge to call the method from outside that file.

The third code snippet calls a details method that gives me a JSON document that contains the parent field with a list of all the elements that are parents of the current element.  If any of those parents are not present in stream, then add them and look for their parents.  Basically, I am just trying to return a list (in no particular order), of all of the parents of an element.  It could be one or it could be 100.

As I said above, my code only returns the immediate parents of the element, then it continues calculating all of them.  Unfortunately, I do not get the full result it ends up calculating.  How can I return the full result?